# Object reference not set to an instance of an object vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, properties, reference

All i want to do is access my property from a parent Form in vb.net Forms. 
but it won't let me do

```
 Dim formParent1 As formParent

 Private Sub search()
 formParent1.propertyName = 1
 End Sub
```

but it gives an error at formParent1.propertyname = 1. Saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

but i may not use

```
Dim formParent1 as formParent = new formParent()
```

how can I access this propery, I am new at VB.net
best regards

Comment: To save a few keystrokes, you could use `Dim formParent1 as New formParent()` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, that code is inside a child form of formParent. To use a reference to the current formParent you need to pass inside the child form a reference to this current formParent.

So in the formParent, when you start the execution of the child form, write this:

```
Dim f as formChild = new formChild(Me)
f.ShowDialog()
```

in the form child constructor save the passed reference to the global variable formParent1

```
Dim formParent1 as formParent ' this is the global level reference to the parentForm'

Public Sub formChild(ByVal f as formParent)
       formParent1 = f
End Sub
```

now you can use the reference formParent1 inside the child form without initialize another formParent
For example, assuming that the formParent1 contains a public property named `SearchResult`, when you complete your search you call:

```
Private Sub searchBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
     Dim searchResult as String

     ' Here write the code that executes the search and set the value in searchResult variable

     ' Pass the searchResult variable to the parent form via the global reference.
     formParent1.SearchResult = searchResult
End Sub
```

Comment: I almost thought that was the answer, but apparently doesn't work on an event this way.

Comment: Could you explain me what do you mean 'doensn't work on an event' ?

Comment: Private Sub SearchBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchBtn.Click  - if I put the argument inbetween that, it says it cant handle it

Comment: Method 'Private Sub searchBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs, formParent As Basis.ParentForm)' cannot handle event 'Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' because they do not have a compatible signature

Comment: 'Private Sub searchBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click` then inside the event code use the parentForm. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep a reference to the form instance in a global variable.

Create a module - in it put:

```
Private _globalParentForm as parentForm = Nothing

Public ReadOnly Property GlobalParentForm as parentForm
    Get
        If _globalParentForm Is Nothing Then _globalParentForm = New parentForm
        Return _globalParentForm        
    End Get
End Property
```

Then you can access the parent form reference in your search form:

```
GlobalParentForm.SearchProperty = searchText
```

Comment: there are some load options in the parent, if I use "new" then it won't load in the database datacontext. Because you see, this child form is a searchForm. And I want to send the search.text and option to the parent without having to load in the database again.

Comment: @deltu100 OK I think I understand now what you are trying to do - have a look at my edited answer

Comment: Then you must be accessing the form before it is loaded (or else you have unloaded the form). I will update my answer to provide a singleton accessor so this can't happen